# Connecting to an external MS SQL Database using Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure

I published my website using Azure and when I go to the sie I'm getting a SQL error:

SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.

I am assuming:

1. That Azure cannot find/process the connection to the external MS SQL server that is in the web.config file. I know that the settings are correct because when I launch the site locally, it connects to the database and retrieve the data.
2. It could also be that I'm using the free (one month) subscription and I'm not sure if that feature is supported.

I found an article (http://blog.davidebbo.com/2012/09/managing-database-connections-in-azure.html) that spoke about "Managing database connections in Azure Web Sites", but I cannot seem to be able to replicate the steps necessary to achieve this external connection.

Comment: 1) This issue has nothing to do with using a free subscription. 2) Have you confirmed that your SQL Server is reachable from outside the data center / premises it resides in?

Comment: Since allowing all IP from an Azure Data center is not safe for you database at all, a better solution would be using hybrid connection or VNet Integration. You can have a look at these 2 articles: [Connect to on-premises SQL Server from a web app in Azure App Service using Hybrid Connections](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/) and [Integrate your app with an Azure Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet/)

Comment: I'm not sure if any of the two articles that you mentioned above would help my situation.  There's got to be a more strait forward way to tell Azure, "Hey, I have an external SQL database. Here are the the properties/connection string to use in order to communicate with it." End of story...

Comment: @solows There is no magical Azure setting to access your on-prem resource. That is fully under your control, not Azure's (which is the basis of my comment above, where you need to confirm that your SQL instance is reachable from outside your on-prem network). It's either that, or creating a vpn tunnel as others have suggested.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is nothing to do with your webapp or Azure Subscription. I understand that you are trying to connect your on premise database from your Azure app. It wont work directly and you need to establish a hybrid connection for the same. You can find the guidance [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-hybrid-connection-connect-on-premises-sql-server/).

Comment: Sorry but 1) you're guessing and 2) what you stated ("it won't work directly") is **not true** regarding direct connection from an Azure app to an on-premises database. You do *not* need a hybrid / vpn connection, if there's whitelisted IP addresses allowed to access a particular on-prem resource.